# Spark stream job with 2 concerns, what is the best practise

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

If a Spark Steaming job has 2 concerns, I am looking for what the best practise would be in this scenerio.

This streaming job is listening on 3 kafka topics.
    Signal topic
    Tweets topic
    Instagram topics

The stream job either consumes a kafka topic for Tweets 
or
the stream job consumes a kafka topic for instagram messages.

So based on the "signal topic", the stream will either consume messages on the Tweets or Instagram kafka topic.

First of all, is it possible for a Spark stream job to be able to alternate like this?

What is the best practice in this use scenerio?

If I did this with 2 spark stream jobs, I would have to somehow be able to pause one of the jobs as only 1 can be running at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. `DStreams` cannot be paused or modified once created. I would say you have 2 choices:

- keep application as and ignore one stream based on "signal". It is involved and would require low level API to avoid unnecessary data load. If your happy with a naive solution you could try:

  ```
  var readTwitter: Boolean = ??? // Varies from batch to batch
  val twitterStream = twitterSource.filter(_ => readTwitter)
  val instagramStream = instagramSource.filter(_ => !readTwitter)
  ```
- alternate process upstream to redirect messages to a single stream based on the "signal" and keep app ignorant to what is going on.

Comment: Any leads on which low level API would be required?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion any Streaming job should only be triggered by an Event. You should not come in the way of how streaming job is triggered.

And, in your case why can't you separate the concern's.Let your signal topic be streamed by Job1 and this decides which job to be triggered.

For this let the Job1 push a message into topic 2 if it needs to trigger Job2 else let it push the message into topic 3 if it needs to trigger Job3.

Job2,Job3 can be a non-streaming job's which totally depends on the events generated by Job1. I hope this gives you another perspective to what is being thought.